# Утечка памяти в результате исполнения кода на JS

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста где проблема: вот код

```
chunk(array, size) {
    if(size == undefined) {
      size = 1;
    }
    let arrayChunks = [];

   for(let i=0; i<array.length; i+size) {
     let arrayChunk = array.slice(i, i+size)
     arrayChunks.push(arrayChunk);
   }


    return arrayChunks;

  }
```

Это метод в объекте с именем "_".

Метод делит массив на части. Каждая часть с кол-вом элементов size. Далее каждая часть (представляющая массив) помещается в новый массив как отдельный элемент.
Работает не как надо но мне нужно чтобы он хоть как-то отработал..
Запускаю из командной строки - ничего не происходит...
Где тут можно ошибиться - не понимаю...один цикл в две строчки...че еще надо ему...
Буду благодарен за подсказку

Вот вызов метода: console.log(_.chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2));

P.S.: задача из цикла упражнений на Сodecademy. там никаких объяснений и подсказок не нашел...

Comment: так а причем тут утечка памяти? что за *объект с именем "_"*? _Работает не как надо_, а как надо и как работает?

Comment: как именно запускаешь _из командной строки_?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под утечкой памяти?

Comment: это упражнение выполняется на Codecademy-сайте где справа своя командная строка.. при вызове метода сыплются куча сообщений о том что "heap out of bound" .запускаю так : node C:\...\_.js. Есть предположение что инкремент в теле цикла должен быть записан не i+size, а i+=size.

Comment: _Есть предположение что инкремент в теле цикла должен быть записан не i+size, а i+=size_ - именно так. Сейчас у тебя просто бесконечный цикл. Только  не в теле цикла, а в определении `for(let i=0; i<array.length; i+=size) {`

Comment: Все..допер..надо было спросить и сразу решение нашлось) благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что Вы не продвигаетесь в перед используя условие i+size, этим условием Вы говорите - На каждой итерации сделай временный результат i+size но не сохраняй его в i. Так Вы попадаете в бесконечный круг повторяющегося условия. 
Попробуйте так:

```
  function chunk(array, size) {
 if(size == undefined) {
     size = 1;
   }
    let arrayChunks = [];

     for(let i=0; i<array.length; i+= size) {
         arrayChunk = array.slice(i,size+i);
         arrayChunks.push(arrayChunk);
      }
  return arrayChunks;
}
```

Comment: что именно поменялось в коде, по сравнению с кодом в вопросе? В чем именно заключалась проблема? Как именно она решилась?

Comment: Подправил Ответ